# How to combine several GAWK statements?

Tags: csv, awk

I have the following:

```
cat *.csv > COMBINED.csv
sort -k1 -n -t, COMBINED.csv > A.csv
gawk -F ',' '{sub(/[[:lower:]]+/,"",$1)}1' OFS=',' A.csv            # REMOVE LOWER CASE CHARACTERS FROM 1st COLUMN
gawk -F ',' 'length($1) == 14 { print }' A.csv > B.csv              # REMOVE ANY LINE FROM CSV WHERE VALUE IN FIRST COLUMN IS NOT 14 CHARACTERS
gawk -F ',' '{ gsub("/", "-", $2) ; print }' OFS=',' B.csv > C.csv  # REPLACE FORWARD SLASH WITH HYPHEN IN SECOND COLUMN
gawk -F ',' '{print > ("processed/"$1".csv")}' C.csv                # SPLIT CSV INTO FILES GROUPED BY VALUE IN FIRST COLUMN AND SAVE THE FILE WITH THAT VALUE
```

However, I think 4 separate lines is a bit overkill and was wondering whether I could optimise it or at least streamline it into a one-liner?

I've tried piping the data but getting stuck in a mix of errors

Thanks

Comment: If you could post sample of input and sample of expected output, it will be helpful for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In awk you can append multiple actions as:

```
pattern1 { action1 }
pattern2 { action2 }
pattern3 { action3 }
```

So every time a record is read, it will process it by first doing pattern-action1 followed by pattern-action2, ...

In your case, it seems like you can do:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
     # remove lower case characters from first column
     {sub(/[[:lower:]]+/,"",$1)}
     # process only lines with 14 characters in first column
     (length($1) != 14) { next }
     # replace forward slash with hyphen
     { gsub("/", "-", $2) }
     { print > ("processed/" $1 ".csv") }' <(sort -k1 -n -t, combined.csv)
```

You could essentially also put the sorting in GNU awk, but that is a but to mimic the sort exactly, we would need to know your input format.